# Android NotificationManager Makes Phone Reboot

Tags: android, notifications, crash, reboot

**Description:**
Every time my application is ran on Android 4.4.4 the user's phone reboots really fast and no crash data is sent to Crashlytics.

When I say the user's phone reboots - it's like the fastest reboot I've seen.

**Application works fine on:**

- 4.1.1
- 6.0.1

**Other Notes:**

- My friend reproduced the bug on his 4.4.4 device
- The background service I create continues after the phone reboots (yes I use a bootReceiver)
- [Link to App on Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.searoth.wallpapercycler)

**When I remove the "addAction" code below, the application works fine:**

```
public void startNotification(){
        final Intent hideNotificationIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HideWallpaperNotificationService.class);
        final Intent stopIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StopWallpaperService.class);
        final Intent wallpaperCyclerIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

        alarmIntent = new Intent(this, SetWallpaperService.class);
        alarmIntent.putStringArrayListExtra(Constants.PREF_WALLPAPERS, mWallpapers);

        PendingIntent nextWallpaperPI = PendingIntent.getService(this.getApplicationContext(), 300, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent stopWallpaperPI = PendingIntent.getService(this.getApplicationContext(), 300, stopIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent showApp = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 300, wallpaperCyclerIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        PendingIntent hideNotification = PendingIntent.getService(this.getApplicationContext(), 300, hideNotificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        //Button
        NotificationCompat.Action stopAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_stop_white_18dp, "Stop", stopWallpaperPI).build();
        NotificationCompat.Action nextAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward_white_24dp, "Next", nextWallpaperPI).build();
        NotificationCompat.Action removeAction = new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_18dp, "Hide", hideNotification).build();

        Bitmap original;
        if(lastSelected == -1)
            original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mWallpapers.get(0));
        else
            original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mWallpapers.get(lastSelected));

        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_fit)
                        .setLargeIcon(original)
                        .setWhen(0)
                        .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this.getApplicationContext(), R.color.colorPrimary))
                        .setContentTitle("Wallpaper Cycler")
                        .setContentText("Click to open")
                        .setContentIntent(showApp)
                        .addAction(stopAction)
                        .addAction(nextAction)
                        .addAction(removeAction);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification n;
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            n = mBuilder.build();
        }else{
            n = mBuilder.getNotification();
        }
        n.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
        try{
            notificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, n);
        }catch(Exception e){Log.e(TAG,"Error notifying");}
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the Bitmaps were too large so I used the below function to resize them.

```
    Bitmap original;
    if(lastSelected == -1)
        original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mWallpapers.get(0));
    else
        original = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mWallpapers.get(lastSelected));

    original = returnBitmap(original,150,320);


public Bitmap returnBitmap(Bitmap originalImage, int width, int height){
    Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)width, (int)height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    float originalWidth = originalImage.getWidth();
    float originalHeight = originalImage.getHeight();

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

    float scale = width / originalWidth;

    float xTranslation = 0.0f;
    float yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale) / 2.0f;

    Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
    transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
    transformation.preScale(scale, scale);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);

    canvas.drawBitmap(originalImage, transformation, paint);

    return background;
}
```